# Send username and password encrypted yii

Tags: php, encryption, yii, password-encryption

Hy everyone, sorry for my bad english.

This is my situation:

- I make an alumni web using Yii
- I encrypt the password with `crypt(password)`
- Registration step is:
- *alumni fill name, address, email, no.id when they school
- *admin, confirm that person. If data valid
- *admin, fill username and password for that person then save to Database
- *admin, go to the web (admin form) then click 1 button which automatically to send username and password.

So my question is:

1. Is my step correct?? or have any idea??
2. I know how to send user and pass automatically, but the problem is, how to send password which have been encrypted?? I have an idea to make 1 field which save password which not encrypted, is my idea correct??

Answer (score 0):

Change your workflow such that password is left empty until the admin clicks the button.

Then generate a random password and send the temporary plaintext password to the user, followed by hashing the password and saving to database in one step.

By the way, you do not want to encrypt the password (i.e. allow it to be reversed into plaintext), but hash it. When the user enters their details into the login form, hash that inputted plaintext password and compare with the hashed password in the database.

Comment: Nice one, i think that password generator is the solution. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: And please, please read up on BCrypt. Using crypt is a great way for your passwords to all be stolen in the future.